# Sum of a repeating pattern of numbers

Tags: number-theory

Consider a pattern, in which 5 repeats 3 times & 4 repeats 1 time.
$$5,5,5,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,4,...$$

Help me find terms count, when sum of the pattern is at least **S**.

For example,
if **S**=29, pattern would be $5+5+5+4+5+5=29$, terms count is 6.
if **S**=20, pattern would be $5+5+5+4+5=24$, terms count is 5.

Comment: To find out the number of blocks $5-5-5-4$, just calculate $\lfloor \frac{S}{19} \rfloor$

Comment: Thanks Peter, 
I need to find exact terms

Comment: Well, the rest is easy. Just think about what to do next. If you denote the number of my above comment with $k$, subtract $19k$ from $S$ to get the rest and the number of terms is $4k$ at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have cycles of $$5+5+5+4$$ and may be a few extra terms.

We have  $$5+5+5+4=19$$ so the first step is to divide your S by 19 and then fit the remainder into your cycle.

For example if you have $S=123$, then $123= 6(19)+9$ so you have 6 cycles and the remainder of 9 indicates that you can  fit two $5$ into your string.

Therefore the length of your string is $6(4)+2 = 26$ and the string is $$5+5+5+4 + 5+5+5+4 +5+5+5+4+5+5+5+4+5+5+5+4+5+5+5+4+5+5$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=19\cdot n+k$ where $n,k\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $k<19$. We choose $19$ because the pattern repeats completely each 4 Digits and they sum up to 19. Hence we have at least $4n=4\lfloor \frac{S}{19}\rfloor$ terms.

So we have determined $n$ and therefore $k$. That is enough to calculate the remaining Terms. You can make a table for the 19 cases ($k=0,\ldots,18$) and if you try some pattern recognition yourself, find an exact formula.

Comment: $\lceil\frac{k}{5}\rceil$ should work for the extra term